# Display .log content from server in local browser with help of URL

Tags: java, html, tomcat

We are connecting to remote machine, and then retrieving .log files to local to have a look at the logs. But is there a way I can use a ULR in browser such that logs would be displayed as an when the log content is getting logged in the file.

Thanks,
Rajesh

Comment: So you want to hit `http://myserver/logs/some_log_file.log` and have it return the log file?

Comment: http://myserver/logs/some_log_file.html as logging is being done at the server side on logfile.log, the html should get refreshed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing in Tomcat that will do this out of the box; otherwise it would be a big security hole :)

What you probably want to do is write a servlet that will fetch the log file for you, format it in some way, and provide automatic refresh (doing a periodic refresh isn't a problem -- `<META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH"... />`, it's getting the log in the first place that's a problem).

Your log servlet could take the name of a log file as a request parameter and then open that log file and basically dump it to the output stream. If you wanted to get cute, you could accept some optional parameters to only fetch the last *N* lines of the file, or only log entries since some date in the past.

Remember to properly-configure security around this service, because being able to look at arbitrary log files is a very sensitive thing.